# Jquery, some objects in class animation

Tags: jquery, class, animation

I'd like to do search animation like on twitter.com
It means that when the user put the cursor over one element some other will be animated also.

I try to do it in that way:

```
$(".classinput").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1,
        });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.5,
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. Moving the mouse over the element animate the single element not the whole class.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate all items of the class when any are hovered, you need to do it like this:

```
$(".classinput").hover(function(){
  $(".classinput").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
}, function(){
  $(".classinput").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
```

Note also I removed the trailing comma after the opacity value, this would cause issues in IE.  Also I'm using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which maps to [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to simplify it a bit.  Also add a [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in there to prevent animation queue build-up on quick hovers.